# Given the Lagrangian of a system, is there a way to extract the total energy?

Tags: classical-mechanics, energy, lagrangian-formalism, relativity

If an object of mass $m$ is under the action of a conservative force and there are no constraints on the system, can $E=K+U$ be obtained? If yes, I am more interested if the answer could be generalized to a **massless** object (under the same assumptions), in which case the energy would not necessarily mean $K+U$ (but this doesn't matter as long as it's the total energy).

Answer (score 3):

Well, within the [Lagrangian formalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_mechanics) with a Lagrangian $L(q,\dot{q},t)$ the energy function is defined as
$$h(q,\dot{q},t)~:=~\sum_{j=1}^n\dot{q}^j\frac{\partial L(q,\dot{q},t)}{\partial \dot{q}^j}- L(q,\dot{q},t).\tag{1}$$
If the system has time translation symmetry, the energy (1) agrees with the corresponding conserved [Noether charge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem). We should stress that this notion of energy (1) does not always coincide with the total [mechanical energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechanical_energy).

References:

1. H. Goldstein, *Classical Mechanics;* Chapter 2.

Comment: I’m curious as to why you’d call $h$ the energy function in general as it will coincide with the energy only if $p\dot q=2K$ (there is a sharper criteria that I can’t remember right now but this is roughly right), i.e. only of the force can be derived from a potential and there is no constraint. I realize that $h$ may still be conserved yet you seem to identify it with the energy *in general*, even without the assumptions of the OP.

Comment: I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

We can derive a total energy from the system if and only if the Lagrangian has a time translation symmetry.

If this is true, then [Noether's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem) tells us how to extract the energy, which is the conserved quantity associated with the time translation symmetry.